# Where clause error.

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i have a question about a value equal or greater than value from other table.
what i am trying to do is to check in the characters fulfills the requirements in Agi that talents has. in this situation the R_Agi for the talent is 30. so i tried to do this:

```
SELECT character_.Name_, character_.Agi, Talents.R_Agi, Talents.SkillName  
FROM character_, Talents
WHERE character_.Agi >= 30
AND Talents.SkillName = 'ambidextrous';
```

but when i change WHERE character_.Agi >= 30 so some smaller value it will also list character when lower than 30. and i only want to show the ones that are = or greater than 30.

after that i tried to do this:

```
SELECT character_.Name_, character_.Agi, Talents.R_Agi, Talents.SkillName  
FROM character_, Talents
WHERE Talents.SkillName = 'ambidextrous'
AND character_Agi >= talents.R_Agi;
```

but get an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'character_Agi' in 'where clause'
```

what would you suggest that i do?

Comment: Should there be a `.` like this: `character_.Agi >= talents.R_Agi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a `.` in the last line

```
SELECT character_.Name_, character_.Agi, Talents.R_Agi, Talents.SkillName  
FROM character_, Talents
WHERE Talents.SkillName = 'ambidextrous'
AND character_.Agi >= talents.R_Agi;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the column qualifier missing.

Change:

```
AND character_Agi >= talents.R_Agi;
```

To:

```
AND character_.Agi >= talents.R_Agi;
```

Comment: thanks alot lads, that was the error, stupid me for not seeing it >.<

Answer (score 1):

Where is the join for those 2 tables in first query?

```
FROM character_, Talents
```

And try to use explict joins and not enumering all tables at the from clause.

And you missed a "." in the join at the second query.

Comment: hmm dont understand @jean should there be a join?

Comment: You are doing join Or there's no relation between tables, pick one. Listing the two tables in the from clause means select ill iterate over each matching row from first table and for each such row ill iterate over each row in second table matching filter, in fact its a 2 nested loops. If there are no join clause you are luck there are just one matching row in talents table or otherwise you ill get duplicate character rows because you are doing a cartesian product.

Comment: is this not the join? AND character_.Agi >= talents.R_Agi; it takes the value from character_ and talents table?

Comment: Yes it is! You missed that in first query?

Comment: hehe okay, sorry about that, but yes it has been added.        SELECT character_.Name_, character_.Agi, Talents.R_Agi, Talents.SkillName  
FROM character_, Talents
WHERE Talents.SkillName = 'ambidextrous'
AND character_.Agi >= talents.R_Agi;